# partykit: data_party on nodeprune`d tree (how/when should `nodeprune` rename nodes in `fitted`?)

Tags: r, party

The behavior of `data_party` does not seem consistent on objects that have been `nodeprune`d. The most salient problem is that, after a `nodeprune` operation, the root node sometimes seems to only contain the data from only one of the branches. Examples follow.

```
##################################################
####
#### First, two examples that show the problem
####
##################################################

#### glmertree example
## Data and fit from glmertree vignette 
## https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmertree/vignettes/glmertree.pdf

data("MHserviceDemo", package = "glmertree")

MH_tree <- lmertree(outcome ~ 1 | cluster_id | age + gender + emotional +
                        autism + impact + conduct, data = MHserviceDemo)

## Both have 350 rows
nrow(MHserviceDemo)
nrow(data_party(MH_tree$tree, 1))

## Prune: only the first left and child descendants
MH_2_5 <- nodeprune(MH_tree$tree, c(2, 5))

## n reported in nodes 2 and 3 is what we would expect (sum of
## former children nodes)
MH_2_5 

## 350: the complete data
nrow(data_party(MH_tree$tree, 1))


nrow(data_party(MH_2_5, 1)) ## 162: so only left child: missing 188
nrow(data_party(MH_2_5, 2)) ## 162: OK
nrow(data_party(MH_2_5, 3)) ## 0: why?


####   lmertree example. 
##  Data and fit from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/mob.pdf, pp. 24 and ff

data("TeachingRatings", package = "AER")
tr <- subset(TeachingRatings, credits == "more")

(tr_tree <- lmtree(eval ~ beauty | minority + age + gender + division +
                       native + tenure, data = tr, weights = students, caseweights = FALSE))


tr_25 <- nodeprune(tr_tree, c(2, 5))

nrow(data_party(tr_tree, 1)) ## 436
nrow(data_party(nodeprune(tr_tree, 1))) ## 436

nrow(data_party(tr_25, 1)) ## 250  : missing 186


##################################################
####
#### And one example that does not show the problem
####
##################################################

## Data and fit from
## https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/vignettes/ctree.pdf, p. 12
data("GlaucomaM", package = "TH.data")
gtree <- ctree(Class ~ ., data = GlaucomaM)
gt_25 <- nodeprune(gtree, c(2, 5))

nrow(data_party(gtree, 1)) ## 196
nrow(data_party(gt_25, 1)) ## 196
```

It seems that the behavior of `nodeprune` is not consistent. Is it possible to obtain the same behavior in lmertree objects as with ctree objects?

It is possible, by hacking the object after pruning. Looking at the code for `data_party` shows that the problem arises here:  `wi <- party$fitted[["(fitted)"]] %in% nt` (where `nt <-  nodeids(party, id, terminal = TRUE)`). Because of the pruning, the nodes in the pruned tree will be 1, 2, 3, .... But the values in `fitted` could be, say, 2 and 5 (the original node ids), not 2 and 3; it seems that pruning, at least sometimes, does not change the node ids stored under `(fitted)` so that they would correspond to the new node ids.

For example, in the MH_tree example (the first example above) we can forcibly rename all former 5s to 3s:

```
MH_2_5$fitted[["(fitted)"]][MH_2_5$fitted[["(fitted)"]] == 5] <- 3
```

and now things are OK:

```
nrow(data_party(MH_2_5, 1)) ## 350
nrow(data_party(MH_2_5, 2)) ## 162
nrow(data_party(MH_2_5, 3)) ## 188
```

However, I do not think we are supposed to do these sorts of things. What am I doing wrong? Should `nodeprune` rename the node ids in `party$fitted[["(fitted)"]]`? The `nodeprune` function does indeed rename the nodes. But the call `nodeids(x) <- newids` does not seem to do what it should with `modelparty` objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer a problem as of 2020-07-22, using version 1.2.10 (obtained from the SVN repo)